# Schema and subdocs in mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Learning how to use mongoose, and am trying to design reliably-variable schemas. The app would post to different services (e.g. Twitter, Tumblr) and store them in one collection ("Posts"). There would be some commonalities (e.g. when it was published, or a short summary) but other fields (like post contents, a blog posts's accompanying scripts) would vary.

What's a good way to approach this? Is there a good way to bind together different collections to avoid this in the first place? References/subschemas? Use `Schema.Types.Mixed`, and reinforce consistency by extending the default methods with safety checks?

```
// Example pseudo-functioning schemas
const tweetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tweetUrl: {type: string, trim: true}
  length: Number
});

const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  edits: [Date],
  slug: { type: String, trim: true},
  body: String
});

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  published: Date,
  summary: String,
  type: String,
  contents: blogSchema || tweetSchema
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [`discriminators`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) could be better option for your case.

> Discriminators are a schema inheritance mechanism. They enable you to have multiple models with overlapping schemas on top of the same underlying MongoDB collection.

Sample codes as below

```
var options = {discriminatorKey: 'contents'};
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  published: Date,
  summary: String,
  type: String,
}, options);
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

const tweetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tweetUrl: {type: string, trim: true}
  length: Number
}, options);
var Tweet = Post.discriminator('Tweet', tweetSchema);

const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  edits: [Date],
  slug: { type: String, trim: true},
  body: String
}, options);
var Blog = Post.discriminator('Blog', blogSchema );
```

Comment: That looks an awful lot like what I'm looking for—thank you!